# Using inline jQuery with Handlebars.js templates?

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js, sammy.js

I'm using Sammy.js to handle routing/app logic and Handlebars.js for templating.  I would like to set up some simple jQuery events to make the UI dynamic (toggling elements, etc).  For example:

```
$("#availability").click( function(e) {
    console.log("hi2");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Currently, I can do this by placing the jQuery events inside of the Sammy.js app but this feels very messy:

```
this.get('#q=:query', function(context) {
    var query = context.params.query,
    loadOptions =   {
                      type: 'get', 
                      dataType: 'json',
                      data: {query: query},
                      cache: CACHE_ENABLED
                    };

    context.load("search.php", loadOptions)
            .then(function(products) {
                 context.query = query;
                 context.products = products.hits.hits;                         
                 return context;
            })
            .partial('/js/templates/search.hb')
            .replace('body')
            .then( function () {
                $("#availability").click( function(e) {
                    console.log("hi2");
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
});
```

Is there a way to initialize these types of jQuery events inside the Handlebars template itself, or with a Helper?  I've tried to register some custom Helpers but the events are never fired.

I would like to keep "UI Logic" separate from the main application logic, since it clutters up my main Sammy.js code and makes it difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

Still haven't found a method to include inline jQuery in the Handlebars template, but I have found a better way to include it in the Sammy app.  I've removed the code to a Sammy Helper and call that, which helps de-clutter the main portion of the app.

```
var app = Sammy("body", function() {

    this.use('Handlebars', 'hb');

    this.helpers({
         jq_clickEvents: function() {
             $("#availability").click( function(e) {
                    console.log("hi2");
                    e.preventDefault();
              });

         }
    });

    this.get('#q=:query', function(context) {
        var query = context.params.query,
        loadOptions =   {
                  type: 'get', 
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: {query: query},
                  cache: CACHE_ENABLED
                };

         context.load("search.php", loadOptions)
                .then(function(products) {
                    context.query = query;
                    context.products = products.hits.hits;                         
                    return context;
                 })
                .partial('/js/templates/search.hb')
                .replace('body')
                .then('jq_clickEvents');
     });
});
```